# window.focus() is not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Here is my code:

```
var myWindow = window.open('','zzz','width=600,height=700');
myWindow.document.write('test');
myWindow.blur();
myWindow.focus();
window.onfocus=function(){
    this.document.write('<br />Focused!');
}
var w = window;
myWindow.onfocus=function(){
    this.blur();
    this.document.write('<br />Focusing on main window!');
    w.focus();
};
myWindow.focus();
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/nMGNS/

When the popup window is **focused** it should print `Focusing on main window!` on the popup and then focus on the main window and print `Focused!` over there.

But it does not.

Here is the information about my browser:

```
Google Chrome   22.0.1229.79 (Official Build 158531) m
OS  Windows
WebKit  537.4 (@129177)
JavaScript  V8 3.12.19.11
Flash   11.3.31.331
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4
```

---

*Aside*:

I know about the `alert(...)` hack, and I want to avoid it.
    ​

Comment: You can not use `document.write` after a page load. If you want to test, use the browser's console. e.g. `console.log("here");`

Comment: @epascarello it was just a quick example. both will work. And also -- of course I can do `document.write` after the page load... it will work perfectly fine....

Comment: The document.write after the page load replaces the page content, it wipes away what is there. You can do it, but it destroys the page by overwriting it!

Answer (score 0):

By @epascarello's comment,Changing `document.write` to `alert`,It can be work in chrome:

```
var myWindow = window.open('','zzz','width=600,height=700');
myWindow.document.write('test');
myWindow.blur();
window.onfocus=function(){
    alert('Focused!');
}
var w = window;
myWindow.onfocus=function(){
    this.blur();
    alert('Focusing on main window!');
    w.focus();
};
myWindow.focus();
```

Comment: Also this does not seem to work. I just tried it in a fiddle to no avail: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/nMGNS/3/

Comment: I think this can not be achieved in chrome, continuous focus will be shielded in chrome